# Ubuntu: how to expand/minimize terminal window by a keymap?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

I'm looking for a shortcut-key that once I click on it, the terminal windows expands, and another shortcut-key that brings the terminal window size to its original size (It's important that I won't need to use the mouse).

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>super</kbd>+UP arrow. to maximize your terminal window. this keyboard shortcut will work on all applications. to bring it back to normal size, use the shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SUPER</kbd>+DOWN arrow. The super key is the key with the windows logo on it.

Additionally, you can also make your own keyboard shortcuts in Settings>Keyboard>Shortcuts by going to the "Windows" tab, selecting the shortcut assigned to 'maximize window" or "Restore window" and typing your own preferred shortcut.

Comment: Thanks. 
I also want to ask how to change the default dimension of "maximize window". I want a bigger window than the regular one, but not so big as the default dimensions.

Comment: @CrazySynthax I'm afraid I do not really know that, maybe you should ask that as a separate question. Also If my answer solves your problem please accept the answer

Comment: What is the `Super` key in a Windows keyboard?:
I found out! it's "windows" + UP arrow